# Geofence and send push notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native, geofencing

before I learn react native from scratch, I was wondering if it is possible to geofence certain areas and then send push notifications to the user when he enters the geofenced areas even if he is currently not using the app. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can access official documentation of Push Notification:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html

Added a sample apps for you to take a look:

- https://github.com/transistorsoft/rn-background-geolocation-demo
- https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Basically you should enable push notification in your project and save the location you get from the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback somewhere in you app, you could use `AsyncStorage` for that purpose. callback is only called if the location is changed.